# Log4net with a Windows Service

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging, windows-services, log4net

I'm trying to get log4net working for a Windows service. It works fine for a console application.

I've created a blank service and the only thing it should do is write out a log statement to a file.

This is my main method.

```cs
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

log.Info("Test");

ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
{
    new Service1() 
};
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

This is my app.config file:

```xml
<configuration>
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
</configSections>

<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Test.log" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout" />
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
</configuration>
```

I've also added this line to my AssemblyInfo.cs file:

```cs
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

According to everything I've read online, this should be enough to create the log file in the directory where the service installed from. When this didn't happen, I tried putting absolute directories as

```cs
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("C:\\Users\\Public\\app.config"));
```

and

```xml
<file value="C:\Users\Public\Test.log" />
```

This didn't work either. I thought maybe it was some crazy permissions problem since the service runs under a potentially restricted account, but I've just tried running it as an administrator and the file still isn't created.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a dependency issue with my setup project. The installer wasn't installing the updated project each time, so the changes were being applied, but not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your service cannot write to the path you configure. Try using some dedicated log directory and make sure that the service has enough rights to write to this directory.

If your settings are in the app.config then this is enough to configure it:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```